# Unable to reset model instance attribute in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

Before we start: I have made a very small git repo with seed data and two REST endpoints to test this issue here: https://github.com/juanpasolano/sails-nested-test

So I have 3 models: `Appointment` which has many `procedure` which has one to one `procedureItem`.
Since there is not nested population in sails I am getting `procedures` with `procedureItem` by hand using something like:

```
  Appointment.find(1).exec(function(err, appointments){
        if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
        async.eachSeries(appointments, function(appointment, cb){
            Procedure.find({appointment: appointment.id}).populate('procedureItem').exec(function(errP, procedures){
                if(errP) return cb(errP);
                appointment.procedures = procedures;
                appointment.proceduress = procedures;
                cb()
            })
        }, function(errE){
            if(errE) return cb(errE);
            res.ok(appointments)
```

So the issue is when I want to replace the `procedures`attribute with the new array procedures (which has the nested depth i need) it just doesn't get set, if you hit the endpoints of the demo, there is no `procedures` attribute available.
As a test I have attached the same new procedures array to `proceduress` (double s) attribute and this one gets properly set.
I have tried using the `.toObject()` method with no luck.
Have tried sails 0.10.5 and 0.11.0 with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no *procedures* attribute, as *Appointment* has MANY *Procedure*, so there is no field *procedures* in DB in *Appointment* table. So if you do not populate like:

```
Appointment.find(1).populate('procedures').exec(function(err, appointments){
.....
}
```

There will not be attribute *procedures* in *appointment* Object

Comment: Sure. The problem is that when I try to manually set the procedures attribute, It just doesn't get set. That is why i am so baffled. Please read the problem thoroughly or try the demo. I appreciate the time to respond but your answer doesn't relate to the problem

Comment: I do not see a problem, everything works: http://pastebin.com/A6s9es9L. Anyway I got three questions: 1. What version of Sails do you use? In your repo that is 0.10.5, why? 2. Why won't you simply request like `Procedure.find({appointment: 1}).populate('procedureItem')`? 3. Why are you using Async with DB requests inside it? What for? What if you have 1000 of records and generate 1000 of requests to DB? And you have `if(errE) return cb(errE);` which will generate an exception if _errE_ will be not null.

Comment: About Async. If you need to request number of _appointment_, you can use *where* syntax like `Procedure.find({appointment: [1, 2, 3]}).populate('procedureItem')` and get all _procedures_ for that _appointments_ in one request

Comment: Thank you so much for trying the demo. If I see your results I see there is `proceduress`(double s) and `proceduresss`(triple s) but not `procedures`.  (And that is my stupid mistake since the demo is like that... can you pull master?) As for your Qs I am using sails v0.10.5. 2. I a doing that the thing is I cannot attach that to the main object. 3. I will look into improving the methods.

Comment: @JuanSolano Well, in fact, all I did is `git clone` and then `npm install` to get absent packages. Then `sails lift` and did not write a string at all. So I am confused. May be some kind of problem with version of Node and Npm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79977/discussion-between-juan-solano-and-bulkin).

Comment: To avoid misleading that this case is still open, please took an answer to marked this case as closed.

Comment: This answer is not valid. It doesn't relate to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exactly same problem a while ago, I believe it is because the "procedure" attribute is in use by the model and not be able to set. I end up cloning each row and then the value was able to be set.

To change your code:

```
if(err) return res.negotiate(err);
        var toreturn=_.map(appointments, function(a){
            var b=_.clone(a); // so you clone it to a new obj, then you can set the procedure... 
            b.procedures = 'aaaa'
            return b;
        })
        //res.json(toreturn); // Here you will get appointments with procedures='aaa'
        async.eachSeries(toreturn, function(appointment, cb){
            Procedure.find({appointment: appointment.id}).populate('procedureItem').exec(function(errP, procedures){
                if(errP) return cb(errP);
                appointment.proceduress = procedures;
                appointment.procedures = procedures;
                cb()
            })
        }, function(errE){
            if(errE) return cb(errE);
            res.ok(toreturn)
        })
```

I do not know why this happened exactly, but this is just one solution.

On a side note, may I suggest you instead of doing async for each appoint, will takes a query per appoint, do two big find, and then loop to merge them?

Something like this:

```
var globalApps=[];
Appointment.find().then(function(apps){
    globalApps=apps;
    var appIDs=apps.map(function(a){return a.id}); //Get all appointment IDs
    return Procedure.find({appointment:appIDs}).populate('procedureItem');
}).then(function(procs){ //This procs is all procedures match the ids
    var toReturn =_.map(globalApps,function(a){
        var b=_.clone(a);
        b.procedure=_.find(procs,{appointment:b.id}); //  This is O(n^2) complexity matching, but you can do something smart.
       return b;
    }); 
    // Now you have toReturn as the appointment array.
   return res.json(toReturn);
})
```

I have spent a lot of time on this problem before, glad someone had the same problem

Comment: I am also very glad someone else had this problem. I didn't want to go your way but apparently is the only way. Thanks for the answer and the tip on async. I hope this gets addressed at sails. About the procedure being used by the model... isnt that the purpose of using toObject()

Answer (score 1):

@sgress454 from Balderdash here.  The issue you're encountering is that the `procedures` attribute isn't a plain Javascript variable; it has a "[getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)" and a "[setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)", which are necessary in order to allow these to work:

```
appointment.procedures.add(<some Procedure obj or id>);
appointment.procedures.remove(<some Procedure id>);
```

So attempting to set the `procedures` attribute to a new value won't work, because of the setter.  Cloning the appointment is an acceptable workaround (you can just do `appointment.toObject()`) as it transforms those special attributes into plain old Javascript variables.  But in your case, it seems like you don't actually need to replace the `procedures` array--you just want each procedure's `procedureItem` to be filled out.  And since only attributes representing many-to-many associations have getters and setters, you can accomplish this without any cloning at all:

```js
Appointment
    // Find the appointments
    .find({...some criteria...})
    // Populate each appointment's procedure
    .populate('procedure')
    .exec(function(err, appointments) {
        if (err) {return res.negotiate(err);}
        // Loop through the returned appointments
        async.each(appointments, function(appointment, appointmentCb) {
            // For each one, loop through its procedures
            async.each(appointment.procedures, function(procedure, procedureCb) {
                // Look up the related procedureItem
                ProcedureItem.findOne(procedure.procedureItem).exec(function(err, procedureItem) {
                    if (err) {return procedureCb(err);}
                    // Attach the procedureItem object to the procedure
                    procedure.procedureItem = procedureItem;
                    return procedureCb();
                });
            }, appointmentCb);
        }, function done(err) {
            if (err) {return res.negotiate(err);}  
            res.ok(appointments);
        });
    });
```

Note that there's a lot of optimization that could be done here--you could pluck out all of the `ProcedureItem` IDs after retrieving appointments, look up all the `ProcedureItem` instances at once, and then map them onto the procedures afterwards, saving a ton of queries.